# C++, Is there a way to make a constructor with references that does not copy values?

Tags: c++

```
// C.h
class C {
private:
    A _a_in_C;
    B *_b_in_C; 

public:
    ...
}

// B.h
private:
    A& _a_in_B;

public:
    B(A& a): _a_in_B(a) {}
    ...
```

Object `_b_in_C` is created at some point of `C`'s lifetime by one of the methods. I want `_a_in_C` to be the same object as `_a_in_B`, so that whenever `_a_in_C` is changed, `_a_in_B` is also changed simultaneously.

The problem is that when a new instance of `B` is created, `_a_in_B` receives a temporary copy of `_a_in_C`, which defeats the purpose of using references in `B` and leaves `_a_in_B` full of garbage after the constructor has finished working.

Comment: Show us the call of the constructor, posted code should do what you want.

Comment: Please create a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Note that you should set `_b_in_C` to a null pointer: `B *_b_in_C = nullptr;`, that way you know whether it was already defined or not.

Answer (score 0):

That's a bad idea for multiple reasons. But regardless, yes this can be done by using a pointer to a pointer:

If you have somewhere :

```
A* originalObj = new A()

A** pointer1 = &originalObj
A** pointer2 = &originalObj
```

and you then do

```
originalObj = somethingElse
```

*(*pointer1) and *(*pointer2) will both reflect the change.

You'll have to translate this to your situation, but that's relatively straightforward.